# F# Create an empty Array of a pre-defined size

Tags: list, f#, empty-list

So I'm trying to create an empty Array that is the length of a table row. I know how to get the length of a row, but I haven't got a clue in how to make an array with a pre-defined length. The program i'm making is dynamic so the length of the array will vary depending on the table I'm accessing.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: What do you want the values to be initialised to? You can use `Array.zeroCreate<'T> length` for the default for the element type. There's also `Array.create` and `Array.init` for initialising to a constant value and from a function.

Comment: That's why [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.array-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) exist

Comment: @Sehnsucht F# used different syntax *and* different names for the same things as other languages. One can't be expected to guess that C#'s `new int[15]` needs a separate function in F#

Comment: I wonder if all the elements in the table are the same type. Generally you return a table row as a record. Can you describe more the input and the desired output? Usually you don't need to do this. But maybe all your elements are float and you need the speed of the array...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure thing that's exactly the point why relying on the official documentation is almost mandatory, also googling "msdn fsharp array" isn't that hard

Comment: You can't rely on the documentation if you don't know that something *doesn't* exist. In this case, one has to know in advance that F# doesn't have special array initialization syntax like other .NET languages. Otherwise it's logical to search for a missing syntax

Comment: This was hinted in an earlier comment, but there is a high chance that what you're doing is not a good way of approaching the problem in F#. You can create an empty array (for some definition of empty) and mutate it, but usually you have better approaches available - like using [different collection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/lists) or [sequence expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/sequences). There is a good reason there's no special array initialization syntax in F#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've said you want an **empty** array, so take a look at `Array.zeroCreate<'T>`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.zerocreate%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

> Creates an array where the entries are initially the default value
>   Unchecked.defaultof<'T>.

Example:

```
let arrayOfTenZeroes : int array = Array.zeroCreate 10
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/arrays) page has a lot of useful information on F# arrays - have look through it, it should point you in the right direction.

As Panagiotis Kanavos has pointed out in comments, F# differs from a language like C# for array creation, so I will quote directly from the F# language reference article I've linked to above for clarity:

> Several functions create arrays without requiring an existing array.
>   `Array.empty` creates a new array that does not contain any elements.
>   `Array.create` creates an array of a specified size and sets all the
>   elements to provided values. `Array.init` creates an array, given a
>   dimension and a function to generate the elements. `Array.zeroCreate`
>   creates an array in which all the elements are initialized to the zero
>   value for the array's type.

Comment: The main point here is that F# uses a separate function when other languages use syntax like C#'s `new int[15];`